# C# Decimal user input with response

Tags: c#, output, decimal

First of all I would like to say I am quite new to C# and my knowledge of it isn't that great, however I looked on different sites and have not found a solution (or perhaps I had but I failed at it)
Anyways, I am trying to implement a function where user types his GPA Score (e.g. 4.5) and if it contains letters or other characters (e.g. 4.5a$g) it returns to ask for a numerical number.
Here is what I currently have:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nGPA Score: ");
userinput2 = Console.ReadLine();
int Result = 0;
bool TGPA = int.TryParse(userinput2, out Result);

if (TGPA)
{
     Console.WriteLine(Result);
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numerical value.");
}
```

Comment: I'd dig a bit deeper into the language, most of them have regex (use a regular expression to make sure only numbers and the decimal is allowed in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Please write a loop till you get a valid number ( a decimal in this case) .

```
        Console.WriteLine("\nGPA Score: ");
        string userinput2 = Console.ReadLine();
        decimal Result = 0;

        bool TGPA = decimal.TryParse(userinput2, out Result);

        while (TGPA == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid number, please try again", userinput2);
            userinput2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Result = 0;
            TGPA = decimal.TryParse(userinput2, out Result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> (e.g. 4.5)

That's not an integer.  Try a decimal:

```
decimal Result = 0M;
bool TGPA = decimal.TryParse(userinput2, out Result);
```